How do I add a scanner driver to my Ubuntu 24.04 for use by a flatpak scanner application?
I'm trying to install the simple-scanner app on a new Ubuntu 24.04. It's no longer available as a .DEB but I can install it as a flatpak.
However it wants a scanner driver and the scanner driver that I have (from Epson) installs itself as a .DEB and tries to pull libsane from the repository and fails because it cannot find it (it worked OK on my Ubuntu 22.04 system).
Any solution?

This seems to be the same as this question on askubuntu. Does the answer work for you?

No it doesn't. Still the same problem, the installer looks for a libsane package.


OK, it turns out that 22.04 has both libsane and libsane1 packages, with libsane marked "transitional".

dpkg -l 'libsane*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version         Architecture Description
+++-===================-===============-============-===========================================================
ii  libsane:amd64       1.1.1-5         amd64        API library for scanners [transitional package]
ii  libsane-common      1.1.1-5         all          API library for scanners -- documentation and support files
un  libsane-extras      <none>          <none>       (no description available)
ii  libsane-hpaio:amd64 3.21.12+dfsg0-1 amd64        HP SANE backend for multi-function peripherals
ii  libsane1:amd64      1.1.1-5         amd64        API library for scanners


Listing the contents of libsane (just a couple of doc files) and its dependencies (only depends on libsane1) made me think that libsane is just kept around in case packages want to install libsane and don't know about the libsane1 name.

Fortunately, libsane still exists on Debian repos, so going through this site I could get a libsane_1.2.1-2_amd64.deb that is a close enough match for the libsane1 in 24.04.

dpkg -i libsane_1.2.1-2_amd64.deb installed libsane

Then the Epson driver installed without errors.

simple-scanner (compiled from source) detects the scanner and works OK



You can use XSANE, a tool that works on most printer/scanners. It available in Universe repo. To install :
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install xsane


simple-scanner sees the scanner but says I should install a driver. and the driver i have (Epson) has a .deb with a dependency on libsane. I do have a libsane1 which I suspect is the same thing but I don't know how to either make dpkg think there is a plain libsane or edit the .deb to replace the dependency with libsane1.

Plot thickens!  on my 22.04 have both libsane and libsane1
